# WooCommerce: Add a custom field in Product Short Description meta box

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, custom-fields, meta-boxes

I would like to add a custom field in **Product short description** WooCommerce Meta box.

This meta box is already built but I can't find a way to add an extra field to that meta box.

This is the code I found in woocommerce.

```
add_meta_box( 'postexcerpt', __( 'Product Short Description', 'woocommerce' ), 'WC_Meta_Box_Product_Short_Description::output', 'product', 'normal' );
```

Any help is highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You would need to remove that metabox and add your own.

Comment: @helgatheviking Many thanks for your suggestion. I'll go in that way.

Comment: Interested to see that @LoicTheAztec. I don't see any obvious way to add content to the [`output()`](https://github.com/woothemes/woocommerce/blob/master/includes/admin/meta-boxes/class-wc-meta-box-product-short-description.php#L27-l40) method, but I admit to not digging too deeply in to it.

Comment: @helgatheviking You are definitively right: The only way is to remove it, and get it back with an additional field (big work). It will be easy to add a custom new metabox without removing it.

Comment: @LoicTheAztec That's what I did. Thanks a lot.